# Styling - Bold for Label in <Lightning-Input label="Contact First Name:" > LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

How do I style my input label.

Is there any way to apply the "Bold" to the label in  
instead of using a separate  tag ?

[image]

Comment: How do I bold the label in <lightning-input label="First Name:" name="FirsName">

Comment: You should read the answer given in the question linked by Pranay - TLDR: You can`t do it via component styles - you have no access to lightning-* internals

Comment: As a quick hack you can create fields with blank label and explicitly style the HTML 

`<label class="slds-form-element__label">Test</label>
 <lightning-input type="text" label=" " name="name" ></lightning-input>`